# What is the order that every builds when running Microsoft Unit Test Framework?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, msbuild, mstest

Here's the scoop:
I have a simple test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", DATA_CONN, "myData", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void Test(){}

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {
        RecreateView("myData"); //why I'm doing this is irrelevant to the question
    }
}
```

When I run this in a scratch project, my `AssemblyInit()` method runs first, creates the table, and the test is happy. When I run it in a much bigger project with lots of tests, the test method gets built first with the `[DataSource]` attribute, and then the `AssemblyInit()` method gets called after.
In short:

Small project - Good

1. Assembly init recreates view
2. Test reads view

Large Project - Bad

1. Test reads view
2. Assembly init recreates view

I only have one `[AssemblyInitialize]` method in each project. It also only seems to ever happen locally. Is there a way to guarantee the `[AssemblyInitialize]` method runs before the tests try to read their data?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2989756/unit-testing-datasource-table-gets-read-before-assemblyinitialize-runs

Comment: @stijn, heh, you linked me back to my own bug. I didn't see they posted a new comment back in september though. Interestingly, they say by design it should go 1. DataSource 2. Assembly Initialize, despite it doing the opposite sometimes. Guess I'll have to switch to a setup script.